# mysql - how to create procedure to insert values without duplicating records?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table(Lets call it External table) which i cannot control the data flow and it has no PK, but i was able to create a routine which imports the data from it to my Database. So i decided to create a inside routine on my database to insert the value on a table with an auto incremented PK:

```
--it has no parameters
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Inserting_on_table()

INSERT INTO MyTable(column1,column2,column3,column4,...columnX)
SELECT
ExtTab.Column1,
ExtTab.Column2,
ExtTab.Column3,
ExtTab.Column4,
...
ExtTab.ColumnX
FROM
externaltable  ExtTab
WHERE
'Conditions'
GROUP BY
'columns'
ORDER BY
'Columns'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   column1 = ExtTab.Column1,
   column2 = ExtTab.Column2,
   column3 = ExtTab.Column3,
   column4 = ExtTab.Column4,
        ...
   columnX = ExtTab.ColumnX;

END
```

But for some reason i getting the following error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ExtTab.Column1' in 'Field List'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `VALUES`:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   column1 = VALUES(Column1),
   column2 = VALUES(Column2),
   column3 = VALUES(Column3),
   column4 = VALUES(Column4),
        ...
   columnX = VALUES(ColumnX);
```

`VALUES()`uses the value that would have been inserted for the update.

Comment: none of them are working with values ​​or creating a nickname for ExtTab.Column =(

Comment: @jacobddavis . . . I don't know what your comment means.  `VALUES` does work, although it is deprecated in the most recent versions.

Comment: the real problem is, i forgot to set up the indexes, the syntax was right.

Answer (score 0):

Try aliasing your values, i.e.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(column1,column2,column3,column4,...columnX)
SELECT
ExtTab.Column1 as column1,
ExtTab.Column2 as column2,
```

unless the column names match.